# How to boot Ubuntu Linux from a USB drive?

Tags: 12.04, boot, usb, flash, drive

I created a flash drive with 12.04 Ubuntu on it, because I want to try it and explore it. I can't get my computer to boot from the drive. I used the suggested pendrive program to format the drive. I opened my boot menu when i started my computer and it didn't have the option to boot from the flash drive. Is there anything I can do or should I just give up and burn it to a disk?

Comment: How old is your computer? Even better, what model is it?

Comment: *How* did you create the drive?

Answer (score 1):

You might have to enable the option in the BIOS. It should be pretty obvious once you get into the BIOS. This guide http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/accessbios.htm looks alright.

I may be able to help if you were to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

If your BIOS doesn't have the option to boot from USB as suggested [here,](https://askubuntu.com/a/307057/225694) some BIOS versions will enumerate USB block devices under hard disk boot options (I've seen this on Gigabyte mainboards) and you can find the make and model of your flash drive to boot from there. If that isn't your situation you should go ahead and burn the ISO to an optical disk and boot from that.